# Crash in XSLTProcessor::importStyleSheet()

Tags: php, xml, xslt

Crashed at `$xslt->importStyleSheet();`
I got the `Internal Server Error` on my screen.
But it works when I replace `position()=1` with `false` in `design.xsl`.

- PHP Version 5.3.29
- XML Support active
- XML Namespace Support active
- libxml2 Version 2.9.1
- XSL enabled
- libxslt Version 1.1.14
- libxslt compiled against libxml Version 2.6.19

testxslt.php

```
$xslt = new xsltProcessor;
$xslt->importStyleSheet(DomDocument::load('design.xsl'));
print $xslt->transformToXML(DomDocument::load('data.xml'));
```

data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datalist>
    <data><title>title 1</title></data>
    <data><title>title 2</title></data>
    <data><title>title 3</title></data>
    <data><title>title 4</title></data>
</datalist>
```

design.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/datalist">
        <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="data">
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <li>top of entrylist</li>
            </xsl:if>
            <li><xsl:value-of select="title" /></li>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>       
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Is the XSLT you shown the one that generates the error, or a simplified version? What happens if you replace `position() = 1` with `true()` in your actually XSLT? As an aside, if you type just `false` in your expression, this is simply looking for an element called `false`. You should use `false()` as a boolean expression.

Comment: This is one of the error I got, simplified version. false() is correct as you say. I'm sorry I made a mistake.

Comment: I got the same error when I use "title!=''" or "string-length(title)=0" instead of "position()=1". Is it a bug of libxslt...?